# Xcode Stuck when being Validated

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode5, app-store-connect

I use Xcode 5 , and I am trying now to Validate and then submit an app to the apple store . I press Validate but its being validate but its stuck in that point , and then after long time waiting its rejected for "time out" .

please see the attach screen shots .

[image]

[image]

Comment: This happens. Just keep trying. It may take a few tries or wait until later to try again.

Comment: Yes I am still trying I think there is a problem in the apple servers , thanks for comment  rmaddy .

Comment: Yeah, there's often a problem with the apple servers unfortunately... happens all the time...

Comment: Thanks Lyndsey Scott for comment , yes I think so , the issued solved now , I just tried after 3 hours and issue fixed now without do any thing .so I think its related to Apple Servers .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have seen that error before and with those kinds of errors, there is not really a solution. Try again in a couple of days or contact Apple. Apple is so large that their servers overflow very quickly. I know it's hard to wait, but just get your mind off of it by doing something like taking the time to remove bugs or test.

Thanks, hope it helped! Sorry for the inconvenience!